# Cannot update Hyperlink in Powerpoint via Powershell

Tags: powershell, com, powerpoint

I use powershell to modify a folder of existing pptx files to update a changed Hyperlink url.
For some reason the present samples seem not to work to modify the Hyperlink url.

This is the code I use so far:

```
Add-type -AssemblyName office

$Powerpoint = New-Object -ComObject powerpoint.application
$msoTrue = [Microsoft.Office.Core.MsoTriState]::msoTrue
$msoFalse = [Microsoft.Office.Core.MsoTriState]::msoFalse
$Powerpoint.visible = $msoTrue

$path = "C:\tmp\ppt"

Get-ChildItem -Path $path -Include "*.pptx" -Recurse |
ForEach-Object {
    "Modifying $_.FullName"
    #Open presentation with ReadOnly:False, Untitled:False, Visible:True
    $presentation = $Powerpoint.Presentations.Open($_.fullname, $msoFalse, $msoFalse, $msoTrue)
    
    $OldStr = "\\PLM\MeetingMinutes\"
    $NewStr = "https://corp.sharepoint.com/:v:/r/teams/MeetingMinutes/"

    foreach($slide in $presentation.slides)
    {
        foreach ($h in $slide.Hyperlinks)
        {
            $ppMouseClick=1
                
            if( $h.Address -like "*$OldStr*" )
            {
                $newUrl =  (($h.Address -replace([Regex]::Escape($OldStr), ($NewStr)))) -replace ("\\","/")
                
                if( $h.Parent.Parent.Parent.Parent.HasTextFrame )
                {
                    $_ = $h.Parent.Parent.Parent.Parent.TextFrame.TextRange.Replace($OldStr, "")
                    $text = $h.Parent.Parent.Parent.Parent.TextFrame.TextRange.InsertAfter("`n"+ $newUrl)
                    $text.Font.Size = 10
                    $actionSettings = $text.ActionSettings($ppMouseClick)
                    $actionSettings.Hyperlink.Address = $newUrl
                    $actionSettings.Hyperlink.TextToDisplay  = $newUrl
                    $actionSettings.Action = 7          
                    
                    $urlStart = $text.Find($NewStr)
                    if( $null -ne $urlStart )
                    {
                        $urlStart.Font.Size=7
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    $presentation.Save()
    $presentation.Close()
}
$Powerpoint.Quit()
[gc]::collect()
[gc]::WaitForPendingFinalizers()
```

I can add new strings after the old hyperlink but although I should be able to make the TextRange Hyperlink enabled I get only plain text added.
The closest I could get was to add a new string after the Hyperlink and change the font size of the url to make it more readable.

[image]

Initially I tried simply to update the Hyperlink.Address property, but that did not have any effect. When I try to change the TextToDisplay string then I get

```
Hyperlink.TextToDisplay : Invalid request.  This kind of object cannot have a hyperlink associated with it.
```

Answer (score 1):

I do see that you found an alternative solution using c# to solve this problem but I still wanted to see if a working solution could be done in PowerShell.

---

I have also run into issues with assigning `TextToDisplay` parameter.
For some reason it will set words in a bulleted list that did not have a hyperlink previously to have the old hyper link. In this screenshot the URL did change for the last bullet point but it added the old hyperlink address to the first two bullet points. (original on right)
[image]

The only way I was able to get it to work was by editing the hyperlink object's `TextRange` and setting the text from there. I saw from the documentation [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/powerpoint.hyperlink.texttodisplay) that the `hyperlink.Parent.Parent` should be a [TextRange](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/powerpoint.textrange#properties) and that it has a `Text` property.  So instead of doing  `$hyperlink.TextToDisplay  = $newUrl` I did `$hyperlink.Parent.Parent.Text = $newUrl` which retained the formatting as well as not setting other items to become hyperlinks. As seen bellow the formatting was retained and the other items weren't changed like above. The square was added in my test to make sure the hyperlink changes with other items besides just text.
[image]

I also added a check to make sure that the hyperlink had text to edit in case it was a picture or shape in which case it just changes the hyperlink address and does not attempt to edit the text since there is none.

#### My Solution

```
Add-type -AssemblyName office

$Powerpoint = New-Object -ComObject powerpoint.application

# this threw an error on one of my machines but still worked while having them commented out. 
# the powerpoint window was just not visible while running script
$msoTrue = [Microsoft.Office.Core.MsoTriState]::msoTrue 
$msoFalse = [Microsoft.Office.Core.MsoTriState]::msoFalse
$Powerpoint.visible = $msoTrue

$path = "C:\somepath\"

Get-ChildItem -Path $path -Include "*.pptx"  -Recurse |
ForEach-Object {
    Write-Output "Modifying $_.FullName"
    #Open presentation with ReadOnly:False, Untitled:False, Visible:True
    $presentation = $Powerpoint.Presentations.Open($_.fullname, $msoFalse, $msoFalse, $msoTrue)
    
    $OldStr = "\\PLM\MeetingMinutes\"
    $NewStr = "https://corp.sharepoint.com/:v:/r/teams/MeetingMinutes/"

    foreach($slide in $presentation.slides)
    {     
        foreach ($hyperlink in $slide.Hyperlinks)
        {
            if( $hyperlink.Address -like "*$OldStr*" )
            {
                Write-Output "edit hyperlink"    
                $newUrl =  (($hyperlink.Address -replace([Regex]::Escape($OldStr), ($NewStr)))) -replace ("\\","/")
                # we can only edit the text of a hyperlink if there is text to edit.
                # if a hyperlink is added to a shape or picture for example it would fail if we try to edit the text
                if ( $hyperlink.Parent.Parent.Text -ne $null){
                    $hyperlink.Parent.Parent.Text = $newUrl     
                    # not working correctly?  
                    # $hyperlink.TextToDisplay  = $newUrl               
                    $hyperlink.Address = $newUrl
                    }
                # no Text property found could be shape or image hyperlink. Only edit address
                else{
                    $hyperlink.Address = $newUrl
                }
            }
        }
    }
    $presentation.Save()
    $presentation.Close()
}
$Powerpoint.Quit()
[gc]::collect()
[gc]::WaitForPendingFinalizers()
```

##### Note

Even though it's working with this solution I'm still not sure why trying to edit `TextToDisplay` just doesn't work properly. Or if editing `$hyperlink.Parent.Parent.Text` is technically the correct way of going about this problem. Maybe someone with more knowledge of this could share some insight.

Answer (score 0):

The PPT object model seems not to work. But there are open source alternatives out there. I have used the Nuget package ShapeCrawler which seems to do the job.

```
using ShapeCrawler;
using static System.Net.WebRequestMethods;

namespace PPTReplacer
{
    internal class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            if (args.Length != 2)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("PPTReplacer Inputdir OutputDir");
                return;
            }

            var targetDir = Directory.CreateDirectory(args[1]);

            Dictionary<string, string> replacements = new Dictionary<string, string>
            {
                { "file://corp.com/MeetingMinutes/","https://corp.sharepoint.com/:v:/r/teams/MeetingMinutes/" },
                
            };


            var files = Directory.GetFiles(args[0], "*.pptx");
            foreach(var file in files)
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"Patching {file}");

                try
                {
                    // Open existing presentation
                    using IPresentation pres = SCPresentation.Open(file);
                    foreach (var slide in pres.Slides)
                    {
                        foreach (IAutoShape shape in slide.Shapes.Where(x => x.ShapeType == ShapeCrawler.Shapes.SCShapeType.AutoShape))
                        {
                            foreach (var paragraph in shape?.TextFrame?.Paragraphs)
                            {
                                foreach (var portion in paragraph.Portions)
                                {
                                    if (portion.Hyperlink != null)
                                    {
                                        foreach (var repl in replacements)
                                        {
                                            if (portion.Hyperlink.IndexOf(repl.Key, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) != -1)
                                            {
                                                Console.WriteLine($"Old: {portion.Hyperlink}");
                                                portion.Hyperlink = portion.Hyperlink.Replace(repl.Key, repl.Value, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase).Replace("\\", "/");
                                                Console.WriteLine($"Link: {portion.Hyperlink}");
                                            }
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }

                    pres.SaveAs(Path.Combine(targetDir.FullName, Path.GetFileName(file)));
                }
                catch(Exception ex)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(ex);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```